# How can I make a Pathfinder campaign like the Monster Hunter video game series?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, campaign-development

I was thinking about how one would go about making a [Monster Hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Hunter) (the video game) style campaign for Pathfinder, but I have a small number of problems.

1. Figuring out CR for "Monsters" to fight (Yes I know the Character level rule, but I have not found anything "monstery" at CR 2 or 3
2. Figuring out rewards for a quest system
3. Balancing spellcasters and mundane characters so that neither is underpowered
4. giving a feeling of similar resource management without being too hard on players.

Comment: Even once that is clarified, this is massively broad. You're effectively asking us a range of only slightly related questions.

Comment: Pathfinder has pretty clear help on how to provide treasure, and how to select monsters, so it's unclear what the problem is there. Further, I suspect by “resource management” you mean you want to homebrew something like the MH inventory/crafting system, which is a whole question on its own (and might be too broad on its own, even). Overall, this is vague and all over the place and not going to get answered well in its current form, so I'm putting it on hold as unclear. If you can figure out how to ask about a specific part of this you're having trouble designing, that edit might help.

Comment: Also, please please please spend some time looking at other systems. Pathfinder is not appropriate for almost all of the requirements of all of your questions. Also look up the "sunk cost fallacy".

Comment: Well then. @BrianBallsun-Stanton what system would you recommend I look at? I just assumed 3.5 and pathfinder were sort of a go to starter RPG.

Comment: For *your* requirements of Awesome! .. @SevenSidedDie and I would like to recommend RIFTS. It seems to fit the style of over the top game you want to play. Also, look through our [tag:game-recommendation] games for questions that suit your desired playstyle. 3.5 is *not* a good starter game for the approach you're taking.

Comment: Well. I generally am looking at different styles of play. Looking at a monster hunting style recently, previously looking at more traditional styles before. I'm hoping to get my friends into Tabletop. I hoped to start on pathfinder for the assumption that dungeons and dragons 3.5 (being my original choice until I learned of pathfinder being basically a better 3.5) would be the best start since dnd is the grandad of RPG's. Then as I looked around me I ended up thinking "what would monster hunter pathfinder look like?" and this question was born.

Comment: It's worth asking a game req question featuring the need for a gmpc and whatever tropes interest them the most and a rule set that you all find interesting. But first I strongly recommend reading *Every* [tag:game-recommendation] question to get a sense of what is out there.

Comment: D&D isn't "the best start" exactly because it's the grandfather of RPGs. Almost every edition was written with the assumption that you came from a wargame background, or from previous D&D edition, and have some idea about how the game has to be played and how to make it click. Not every non-D&D game is made for RPG newbies, but some do go great lenghts to explain the mindset, the scope and the techniques needed to enjoy it. (Asking for a game that does this might be a good idea.) D&D is just the 800 pound gorilla, and every edition I know rewards mastery of a huge, "shopping list" game system.

Comment: @Zachiel I'm already asking a question about a starting game here http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62440/is-there-a-rules-light-game-which-supports-classless-characters-simple-and-tact/