# Is there a rules light game which supports classless characters, simple and tactical combat, and the game master running a GMPC?

Tags: game-recommendation

I was told in [How can I make a Pathfinder campaign like the Monster Hunter video game series?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62435/how-can-i-make-a-pathfinder-campaign-like-the-monster-hunter-video-game-series) that I should make a question of what kind of RPG system I should use.

What I want it to be.

- A loose class system or none at all
- a simple but tactical combat style that could work as well for party battle in dungeons as a 1 on 1 duel. Simple but tactical meaning that it requires skill and tactics to overcome, but isn't something that needs a crap ton of explaining to get into
- something that could be easy to go into but well structured to keep things clear.
- something that I could GM and play at the same time. Since I only currently have 2 others within close enough distance to meet on a regular basis.

I've read sources for pathfinder and 3.5 already and really seem to like what it has, but I am also curious about the possibility of finding something even better. So if something similar but improved even more I'm all ears.

On the topic of a "Loose Class system": I was prone to making gestalt builds (as people who read my other questions know) because I wanted a mixed class that let me have different styles of abilities (My main character for example being a 'gish' archetype. And (though I don't mean to be rude) everyone and their grandmother told me gestalt for a first game was a bad idea. So a "loose" class system would let players mix playstyles without screwing themselves over from being a master of none. whilst still being balanced.

Comment: As far as being comfortable with PF/3.x, I'd also point out that most other systems have a much easier learning curve.  Not wanting to go through the same type of learning curve again is understandable, but in most cases it's not necessary.

Comment: I understand your concern with "we're too few and we need a third PC so I, as the Dm will play one". Are games that are viable with only two playing characters a good alternative to "give me a game where I can have a GMPC"?

Answer (score 7):

## [Numenera](http://www.numenera.com/)

In your situation - 2 players, looking for a light system that offers class flexibility - I am currently running a game of Numenera. The setting is a billion years in the future - so it seems like science fiction, but there are many people who regard the strangeness permeating the world as magic instead. It is trivial to describe your world as magical, and use as much or as little of the setting as you like.

Let's look at your criteria:

> A loose class system or none at all

Numenera has only three character Types - what would typically be seen as classes. So obviously, there is plenty of freedom within each of those to develop (and begin) as you see fit. The gist is that Glaives are warriors, Nanos are wizards, and Jacks are everything else, including blends of the other two. You are free to have a party with all of one type, or excluding a type, or mixing them all.

> a simple but tactical combat style that could work as well for party battle in dungeons as a 1 on 1 duel. Simple but tactical meaning that it requires skill and tactics to overcome, but isn't something that needs a crap ton of explaining to get into

The combat system is simple. Players do all the rolling, damage is static (fixed, not rolled), and there are not a million overlapping rules. The same rules that govern all tasks govern combat. However, it **is** tactical because players need to use their powers, equipment, training, and resources advantageously to defeat superior foes. Stats are resource pools, depleted by damage and by Effort - exerted to lower the target number of rolls.

> something that could be easy to go into but well structured to keep things clear.

The game is well written and very clear. The system is simple to explain and learn.

> something that I could GM and play at the same time. Since I only currently have 2 others within close enough distance to meet on a regular basis.

I am not attempting this. But I can tell you why Numenera has low barriers to this play style:

1. You will never roll against yourself - players make all the rolls, so there is no way for you to even seem like you are fudging rolls
2. It's easy to run with public information - the game isn't based on keeping monster stats secret
3. With simple rules and resolution mechanics, it will be easy for your players to see that you are facing the challenges fairly and it will be easy for you to engage as a player in some aspects of the game - like combat

There are going to be some challenges:

1. You will know, obviously, all the secrets and discoveries of the game. Probably better to exclude your PC from those rewards - but your character can serve as a valuable mouthpiece in the game world, too.
2. The system assumes a constant flow of one-use magical items, called **cyphers** will move through your players hands. So much so that the system is called *The Cypher System*. If you are not cool with that, you will have to find some way to replace the bonuses they are expected to provide.

Comment: Well... I may not use this for the fantasy game I hope to play; but I LOVE THIS! i just read the description of the ninth world and I'm really excited and curious about this system and may pull this out as a system to get my friends into tabletop

Comment: The engine is being released as the generic "Cypher System" this summer I believe.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I haven't seen that yet or played it so can't recommend it.